# Bizarre NU1605 referecing NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 when the library of the diversion point is actually referencing netstandard version 2.0

Tags: nuget, .net-5, .net-standard-2.0

The .NET 5 project builds correctly on my workstation, but on the build server it blows up. This problem appeared immediately on upgrading .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5 which coincided with installing .NET 5 on the build server.

Errors from the build server:

```
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605:  Centoscript.Forms -> CentoScript 5.2.0.3 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Console 4.0.0 -> runtime.win.System.Console 4.3.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.3.0)
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605:  Centoscript.Forms -> CentoScript 5.2.0.3 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.0.1)
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Text.Encoding.Extensions from 4.3.0 to 4.0.11. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Diagnostics.Debug from 4.3.0 to 4.0.11. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605:  Centoscript.Forms -> CentoScript 5.2.0.3 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Debug (>= 4.3.0)
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605:  Centoscript.Forms -> CentoScript 5.2.0.3 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Debug (>= 4.0.11)
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605:  Centoscript.Forms -> CentoScript 5.2.0.3 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.3.0)
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605:  Centoscript.Forms -> CentoScript 5.2.0.3 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.0.1)
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Text.Encoding.Extensions from 4.3.0 to 4.0.11. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605:  Centoscript.Forms -> CentoScript 5.2.0.3 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem 4.0.1 -> runtime.win.System.IO.FileSystem 4.3.0 -> System.Text.Encoding.Extensions (>= 4.3.0)
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605:  Centoscript.Forms -> CentoScript 5.2.0.3 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Text.Encoding.Extensions (>= 4.0.11)
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.Diagnostics.Debug from 4.3.0 to 4.0.11. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605:  Centoscript.Forms -> CentoScript 5.2.0.3 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Debug (>= 4.3.0)
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605:  Centoscript.Forms -> CentoScript 5.2.0.3 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Diagnostics.Debug (>= 4.0.11)
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.IO.FileSystem from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605:  Centoscript.Forms -> CentoScript 5.2.0.3 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem (>= 4.3.0)
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605:  Centoscript.Forms -> CentoScript 5.2.0.3 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem (>= 4.0.1)
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version.
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605:  Centoscript.Forms -> CentoScript 5.2.0.3 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.Net.Sockets 4.1.0 -> runtime.win.System.Net.Sockets 4.3.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.3.0)
Centoscript.Forms\Cedaron.Centoscript.Forms.csproj : error NU1605:  Centoscript.Forms -> CentoScript 5.2.0.3 -> NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 -> System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives (>= 4.0.1)
```

Project file for `Centoscript.Forms`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="../AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Common" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="CentoScript" Version="5.2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Project file for Centoscript (unchanged between working and broken--it targets netstandard2.0 for cross-use between core and framework):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
    <AssemblyName>CentoScript</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>CentoScript</PackageId>
    <Version>5.2.0.4</Version>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Common" Version="1.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Dynamic.Runtime" Version="4.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Primitives" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I would suspect we got bad references via `Common` except for the fact that `CentoScript.Forms` uses a much higher version of `Common` that should stomp the references. In any case that is a kind of bad explanation because it was working until the build target of `CentoScript.Forms` was changed from `netcoreapp3.1` to `net5.0`.

I should not have to add references to the listed packages, and I definitely should not add them at either requested version. net5.0 should be picking up much higher versions of them automatically.

Yes I really did mean to put two different .NET version tags. Multiple versions are clearly in play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops the problem was a corrupted nuget cache on the build server.